# Eledmac reference lemma with word rank

Tags: line-numbering, eledmac

Honestly, I don't understand how to use the subline numbering feature. I would expect to be able to refer to the first of two identical words in the lemma of the apparatus.

For example:

> Tertia est – supposito, quod sint passiones totius coniuncti, cum
>   non insint toti nisi ratione partium –, cui parti corporis 
>   uel animae debeant  attribui, utrum uegetatiuae aut sensitiuae aut
>   intellectiuae.
>
> 2.1 aut ] om. M

Here the 2.1 lets us know that the lemma refers to the first instance of *aut* in the second line.
Isn't this possible? I don't understand the use or function of subline numbers as described in the documentation.

Comment: subline number are ... sublines number. Line can have number or subnumber. That means you can have lines like 1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 2, 2.1, 2.2, 2.3.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the possibility to make distinction between to occurence of the same word...

Comment: but, indeed, the actual version of eledmac is buged for subline feature.

Comment: this bug with subline is now closed in the dev version. Let me work for the problem of a terme in two time.

Comment: Well, I completely misunderstood the feature then. But it would certainly be a huge help with automatic distinction between identical words in a line. Should I create a feature request on Github?

Comment: no, a I have already opened a issue fort this problem https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/110. I have some idea to add it, but is more technical that I was thinking.

Comment: Ok, it's working. I have to clean the code and to make a handbook. I will ask you to try it when ok.

Comment: could you make some test? I have add this feature. Read https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/issues/110#issuecomment-68011879 to know how to test. And please answer in the github page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new version 1.15.0 (uploaded yesterday in CTAN)

- fixe the bug with \subline feature
- add new feature to prevent lemma ambiguity. This is work with a new command : \sameword, to mark the words potentially ambiguous.

See the MWE

```
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Leo \sameword{aut} ursus \sameword{aut} oryx \sameword{aut} ricinus \sameword{aut} equus \sameword{aut}
lupus \edtext{\sameword{aut}}{\Afootnote{et}} canis \sameword{aut} felix \sameword{aut} asinus \edtext{\sameword{aut}}{\Afootnote{et}} burricus.

\pend
\endnumbering
```